# If I hover over an element, how can I select all sibling elements before it and including it, in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the html:

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
```

I have the following javascript:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', 'div', function() {
    var elements = ''; // <-- What should I put here?
});
```

If I'm hovering over `div#three` I want the variable `elements` to be a collection of `div#one, and div#two, div#three`

How can I achieve this in jQuery?

Comment: You'd be better off using a common class for all those `div`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
var elements = $(this).prevAll("div").addBack()
```